# MongoDB "Update Where" like in MySQL but for arrays

Tags: mongodb

I want to change a field of an element inside an array in a MongoDB NoSQL dataset. But at the time of the update, I do not know which index the element has due to parallelisation. What I do know are some values that are stored inside of that element.

**My Data**

```
course = {
    _id: ObjectId("some-id"),
    someOtherFields: {
        ...
    }
    myList: [
        {
            uid: ObjectId("some-user-id-1"),
            someField: "value to change",
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Query to show all "courses"s myList entries with a specific uid look like

**my query**

```
db.courses.find(
  {"myList": {"$elemMatch":{"uid":"my-uid-to-find"}}}, 
  {"_id":true, "someOtherField":true, "myList.$":true}
)
```

**question**

> the question is how can I update only this row with a query without
>   knowing its index.
>
> I want to change `someField` of `myList.$` where
>   `myList.$.uid` = `someIdToFind`

Comment: you not define `mailinglist` in your data ?

Comment: oops, sorry, i ment myList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case first you should put all matching criteria of given array values in update query using `elemMatch` as same like in your `find` statement.

Then use [mongo positional operator $](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in update so update query as below :

```
db.collectionName.update({
  "myList": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "uid": "your given ObjectId" // set here ObjectId to find matching element in array
    }
  }
}, {
  "$set": {
    "myList.$.someField": "your updated value" // use mongo postional operator "$" to iterate over array 
  }
})
```