# $push creates a new object with _id only, without properties - feathsjs+mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, feathersjs

I'm trying to insert an object (with one property, text) into an array of a sub-document using $push:

```
await this.app.service("someService").patch(
      null,
      {
        $push: { "subDocuments.$.textArray": { text: "stuff" }}
      },
      {
        query: {
          _id: parentId,
          "subDocuments._id": subDocumentId
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

The model looks like this:

```
const ParentSchema = new Schema({
    subDocuments: [SubDocumentSchema]
});

const SubDocumentSchema = new Schema({ 
     textArray: [
          {
              text: { type: String }
          }
     ]
});
```

The object is created but its an empty object with _id as its only property.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please declare schema like :

```
const ParentSchema = new Schema({
    subDocuments: [SubDocumentSchema]
});

const SubDocumentSchema = new Schema({ 
     textArray: [
          {
              text: { type: String }
          }
     ]
}, { _id: false });
```

Comment: Wouldn't that disable creating ids for the subdocument? That is not what I'm looking for. 
I'm trying to get the array objects (of `textArray`) to be created with the text property

Comment: @C493d Your query and push statement looks fine. I created same document in my local MongoDB query is running fine. You can take reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840945/push-item-in-sub-document.

Comment: Thanks, this is why I'm asking since I don't see why it won't work. It might be a problem with feathersjs